# It's all in here. Nowhere but in the post

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

The answer is in here. You may not realize, but there's 5 letters needed to solve this puzzle right here. ☝

### Hints

Hint #1:

> Comments are useless before you solve partially, just so you know. But they can be helpful after you figure out the amazing ending if overcomed, usually.

Comment: Thoughts: The images may be of a hand creating a shadow..

Answer (score 4):

Are the five letters:

> The 5 vowels?

Because

> There are 5 vowels: a, e, i, o, u.  They are all in the post:
>
>  >Th**e** **a**nswer **i**s in here. Y**ou** may not realize, but there's 5 letters needed to solve this puzzle right here.
>
>  I am only highlighting the first example of each.

Furthermore:

> They are also all in the title:
>
> **I**t's **a**ll in h**e**re. N**o**where b**u**t in the post

I am not sure about what the emoji represent, but my guess is:

> An idea (lightbulb) in the post (finger pointing at post). I got the idea of vowels from the '5 letters', there are 5 vowels and 'vowel' is 5 letters long.

Comment: @haykam the skin tone is important? Shouldn't this have a rebus tag then?

Comment: @haykam I gave up on this long ago but if you are hinting towards stuff in bold, the thanks for the clue

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer(?)

> There is a "hi there!" comment that can be seen in edit mode. Not sure if it is the answer or just me who got trolled.

Comment: Well +1 to you for that. Well done.

Comment: Well, of the three boxes below the question the center one is supposed to be a hand pointing up. I don't know if it's the fact that I don't have that text file on my computer or if it's intentional that the other pics don't show up, but that I imagine has something to do with the puzzle.

Comment: @mkinson shows for me. First one is a light bult, third one is a brown circle.

Comment: These are the 'emoji' names:
Light Bulb,
Index Pointing Up,
Dark Skin Tone

Comment: Is the light bulb on or off?

Answer (score 2):

Is the answer

> simply **emoji**?  The puzzle is just 3 emoji, after all ...

Answer (score 2):

Is the answer

> 'here.' You say the answer is 'here.'

This seems like a lame guess

Answer (score 1):

A guess based on the three images..

> Highlight? Like, for hair?

Comment: I'd like to add that this uses five unique letters, just as the puzzle hints at.